# Curl is not working when database connection is active

Tags: php, curl, mysqli

I have found a very serious and easy to reproduce problem happening with CURL on latest PHP 7.2.X (which is 7.2.24).

Just run the code below on your server running PHP+APACHE+MARIADB:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$opts = array();

$opts[CURLOPT_URL] = "https://www.sitepor500.com.br";

curl_setopt_array($curl,$opts);

echo curl_exec($curl);

?>
```

It will work just fine, I mean, you will see the contents of the page on CURLOPT_URL. Now JUST ADD one single line of code to it and the bug will happen:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","your_password");

$curl = curl_init();

$opts = array();

$opts[CURLOPT_URL] = "https://www.sitepor500.com.br";

curl_setopt_array($curl,$opts);

echo curl_exec($curl);

?>
```

Incredibly, just adding a connection to a local database will make CURL fetch the content of the URL specified at CURLOPT_URL as "" (empty string). This happens with any URL.

NOTE: PHP community confirmed this is a bug and affects all domains with SSL when trying to get their content using CURL. So should I close this issue or delete it?

Comment: I find this hard to believe. Are you sure the rest of the script is actually running? Is it any database connection, or only `mysqli`? What happens if you use PDO instead of mysqli?

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: I am pretty sure of this bug, me and another 2 friends reproduced it. One of my friends even reproduced it on Windows. I can only test `mysqli` on my end. No errors on PHP log of the virtual host that I am using.

Comment: I don't have that version of PHP, but I tried it on 7.3.11 and couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: So if it's a bug, they've fixed it.

Comment: Does it have to be a local database? I used a remote DB, I don't have a local DB on the same machine as my PHP 7.x server.

Comment: @Barmar it only works on 7.2.24 version! It does not need to be a local database, I could reproduce the bug running on my own notebook connected to my server database.

Comment: OK, so what is the purpose of your question? You've identified a bug, but we know that it's fixed. If you're looking for a solution, "upgrade".

Comment: @Barmar I dont know exactly if its a bug! Cause using `file_get_contents` works just fine. Maybe someone knows something on the release notes that I missed that says something about this problem I am facing.

Comment: There's no way this can be intentional. if it's not working, it's clearly a bug.

Comment: NOTE: PHP community confirmed this is a bug and affects all domains with SSL when trying to get their content using CURL. So should I close this issue or delete it?

Comment: You could post an answer with a reference to the bug entry.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! Will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem I reported here looks like a bug specific to the version of PHP I reported - 7.2.24 - and also to the version 7.3.7. The bug is related to the fix "openssl_encrypt_ccm.phpt fails with OpenSSL 1.1.1c" posted in the changelog. They fixed something and broke another.

These 2 bug reports (one mine and another from other user) show the bug happening:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78845
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78824

In my case, this bug only happens when using SSL/HTTP with CURL. If you use any domain without SSL it will work just fine. And you also have to make a database connection before you try to use CURL - if you do so it will trigger the bug.